# Does submit changes work for all linq2sql objects, even if they are defined in seperate files

Tags: linq-to-sql, transactions, atomic

I am trying to get better at my data access patterns, and as such am trying to ensure where needed I am using things with transactions.

I wonder, if I make many changes, across many different Repository Classes (data access classes) and then just call SubmitChanges from one class, will that be safe, even if I have used other classes as part of my transaction.

Is there a good tutorial for best practice linq2sql transactions, and where would I need a more complex solution than the built in transactions of SubmitChanges?

Answer (score 2):

All changes to linq to sql objects belonging to the same DataContext will be committed to the database when SubmitChanges() is called, no matter where it's called from.

Answer (score 0):

> wonder, if I make many changes, across many different Repository
>   Classes (data access classes) and then just call SubmitChanges from
>   one class, will that be safe, even if I have used other classes as
>   part of my transaction.

Yes, that will be safe. As long as you call SubmitChanges once, Linq-2-sql will do all the updates and it will do do so in one transaction that is created for you by linq-2-sql. There is no need to add a separate transaction yourself.

> and where would I need a more complex solution than the built in
>   transactions of SubmitChanges?

Well, all I can think of is if you want to update using separate datacontexts, for example accross multiple databases.